# MapStruct Ignore a property inside a list inside a Object

Tags: java, many-to-many, dto, mapstruct

I have this:

```
@Entity
public class Upgrade {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "UPGRADE_PROJECT", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "UPGRADE_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID"))
    private List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();...}
```

And

```
public class Project {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
    private List<Upgrade> upgrades = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also DTOs resemble the entities.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {VersionMapper.class, ProjectMapper.class,
        YearMonthMapper.class})
public interface UpgradeMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "acquired", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    UpgradeDTO upgradeToUpgradeDto(Upgrade upgrade, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "acquired", dateFormat = "MM-yyyy")
    Upgrade upgradeDtoToUpgrade(UpgradeDTO upgradeDTO, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

}
```

And

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UpgradeMapper.class, YearMonthMapper.class})
public interface ProjectMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "fromDate", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    @Mapping(target = "toDate", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    ProjectDTO projectToProjectDto(Project project, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "fromDate", dateFormat = "MM-yyyy")
    @Mapping(target = "toDate", dateFormat = "MM-yyyy")
    Project projectDtoToProject(ProjectDTO projectDTO, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);
}
```

I use the mapper like these:

```
    CycleAvoidingMappingContext cycleAvoidingMappingContext = new CycleAvoidingMappingContext();
    Upgrade upgrade = upgradeMapper.upgradeDtoToUpgrade(upgradeDTO, cycleAvoidingMappingContext);
    upgrade = setupAndSave(versionId, upgrade);
    return upgradeMapper.upgradeToUpgradeDto(upgrade, cycleAvoidingMappingContext);
```

I get this result when I create an upgrade:

```
{
    "id": 1804,
    "version": {
        "id": 2007,
        "technology": {
            ...
        },
       ..
    },
    ...
    "projects": [
        {
            "id": 603,
            ...
    THIS SHOULD BE IGNORED
            "upgrades": [
                {
                    "id": 1703,

                    "projects": [
                        {
                            "id": 603,

                            "upgrades": [
                                1703,
                                {
                                    "id": 1704,

                                    "projects": [
                                       AND GOES ON AND ON
                                    ],

                                },
                                ..,
                                ..
                            ],
                            ..
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 604,
                            "upgrades": [
                                1703,
                                1704,
                                1803,
                                1804
                            ],
                            ..
                        }
                    ],
                    ..
                },
                1704,
                1803,
                1804
            ],
           ...
        },
        {
            "id": 604,
            "upgrades": [
                1703,
                1704,
                1803,
                1804
            ],
            ..
        }
    ],
    ..
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this

```
public interface UpgradeMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "acquired", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    @Mapping(target = "projects.upgrades", ignore = true)
    UpgradeDTO upgradeToUpgradeDto(Upgrade upgrade, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);
```

But it won't work because `projects` is a List and not an entity.

My current fix is:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UpgradeMapper.class, YearMonthMapper.class})
public interface ProjectMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "fromDate", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    @Mapping(target = "toDate", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    @Mapping(target = "upgrades", ignore = true)
    ProjectDTO projectToProjectDto(Project project, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);
```

So When I get a project entity from the DB and get the DTO, The DTO have `upgrades` empty.

I there a way to acheive my goal without compromizing the other side of the relationship?

Project

```
{
    "id": 603,
    "upgrades": [],
    "createdAt": "10/June/2020  at 14:58:47"
}
```

Upgrade (this is the desired behaviour)

```
{
    "id": 1804,
    "version": {
        "id": 2007,

    },
   ..
    "projects": [
        {
            "id": 603,
            ..
            "upgrades": [],
            "createdAt": "10/June/2020  at 14:58:47"
        },
        {
            "id": 604,
            ..
            "upgrades": [],
            "createdAt": "10/June/2020  at 14:59:59"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "10/June/2020  at 15:59:52"
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on Filip Suggestion now the mappers look like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UpgradeMapper.class, YearMonthMapper.class})
public interface ProjectMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "fromDate", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    @Mapping(target = "toDate", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    ProjectDTO projectToProjectDto(Project project, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    @Mapping(target = "upgrades", ignore = true)
    @InheritConfiguration
    @Named("withoutUpgrades")
    ProjectDTO projectToProjectDtoWithoutUpgrades(Project project, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "fromDate", dateFormat = "MM-yyyy")
    @Mapping(target = "toDate", dateFormat = "MM-yyyy")
    Project projectDtoToProject(ProjectDTO projectDTO, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);
}
```

AND

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {VersionMapper.class, ProjectMapper.class,
        YearMonthMapper.class})
public interface UpgradeMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "acquired", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    @Mapping(target = "projects", qualifiedByName = "withoutUpgrades")
    UpgradeDTO upgradeToUpgradeDto(Upgrade upgrade, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "acquired", dateFormat = "MM-yyyy")
    Upgrade upgradeDtoToUpgrade(UpgradeDTO upgradeDTO, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

}
```

And it still does NOT work, it still uses `projectToProjectDto` instead of `projectToProjectDtoWithoutUpgrades`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the qualifiers to ignore the mapping.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UpgradeMapper.class, YearMonthMapper.class})
public interface ProjectMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "fromDate", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    @Mapping(target = "toDate", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    ProjectDTO projectToProjectDto(Project project, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    @Mapping(target = "upgrades", ignore = "true"
    @InheritConfiguration
    @Named("withoutUpgrades")
    ProjectDTO projectToProjectDtoWithoutUpgrades(Project project, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "fromDate", dateFormat = "MM-yyyy")
    @Mapping(target = "toDate", dateFormat = "MM-yyyy")
    Project projectDtoToProject(ProjectDTO projectDTO, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);
}
```

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {VersionMapper.class, ProjectMapper.class,
        YearMonthMapper.class})
public interface UpgradeMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "acquired", dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy")
    @Mapping(target = "projects", qualifiedByName = "withoutUpgrades")
    UpgradeDTO upgradeToUpgradeDto(Upgrade upgrade, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", dateFormat = "dd/MMMM/yyyy [ 'at' HH:mm:ss]")
    @Mapping(target = "acquired", dateFormat = "MM-yyyy")
    Upgrade upgradeDtoToUpgrade(UpgradeDTO upgradeDTO, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

}
```

This means when the mapping for `projects` in an upgrade is done it will use the mapping without qualified by `withoutUpgrades` for mapping the projects.

Comment: Try to add methods with List.

Comment: Thanks a lot man for your help, I just needed to add other direction of the relationship